# Wordpress media uploader in front end form works but add media button in same form doesn't allow new uploads

Tags: wordpress, wp-editor

I have a front end form allowing logged in users to upload a post with featured image (using wp media button) and images in the text area (the_content) using the Add Media Button of wp editor.
While the wp media button allows the user to upload a new image, the Add Media Button of the wp editor doesn't allow the same user to upload a new image. The error message is "You don't have the permission to attach files to this publication".
I already tried following solutions but without any succes:

1. Added define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); in wp-config
2. removed /*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */ from bootstrap.min.css
3. added the following capabilities to the related role through the php file

   function wpse210884_add_upload_files_cap() {
   $role = get_role( 'specificrole' );
   $role->add_cap( 'upload_files' );
   $role->add_cap( 'edit_post' );
   $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_pages' );
   $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_pages' );
   }
   register_activation_hook( **FILE**, 'wpse210884_add_upload_files_cap' );

The code to display the wp editor in the front end form is the following

```
$settings1 = array( 'media_buttons' => true, 'textarea_name' => 'presentation', 'teeny' => true, 'quicktags' => false );
ob_start();
wp_editor( $oldcontent, "myeditor1", $settings1 );
$editor_presentation = ob_get_clean();
echo $editor_presentation;
```

The Add Media Button of the wp editor allows the logged in user to add an image (that already exists in the media uploader of the user) in the editor, BUT doesn't allow to upload a new image.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the wrong user role. So after setting the right capabailities to the right user role, it works. Take into account that adding the capability edit_published_pages will display in some theme pages a "modify" link on every page of your website for that specific user role, which I didn't want. So I had also to remove the edit_post_link from content-single.php and from content.php